# removeFromParent() strange behavior

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have really strange behavior with function `removeFromParent`

```
lazy var buttonAds: SKSpriteNode = {
  let n = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ButtonAds")
  n.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: 600)
  n.zPosition = 100
  n.setScale(1.4)
  return n
}()
```

in `didMove(...)` add this button with `addChild(buttonAds)`, and latter in `touchesBegan`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  let touch = touches.first!

  if buttonAds.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
    // ...
    doAds()
    buttonAds.removeFromParent()
  }
}
```

If you tap on button for ads, will be removed, but if tap on that place again, this will call function `doAds()` again... it's strange, buttonAd don't exist on scene.

Initial:

[image]

and after tap:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is check if the node you touch is of the type it should be. Change your code to this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) == buttonAds {
        doAds()
        buttonAds.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

This should do the trick!

edit: as to why this works, you're removing the node from the scene but it is still an object in memory (otherwise you wouldn't be able to use `buttonAds.contains(...)` on it) so it also still has its position stored.

Comment: Yes, this do the trick. For Swift4 `atPoint(touch.location(in: self))`. But why first solution not working as expected: to remove from parent